# Fixing the vertical and horizontal position of an element over an image which is set to onbject-fit to contain

Tags: html, css, sass, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I have already several days looking for a solution CSS or component for making an image resizable (height and width) and over the image, elements keeping the position over the same X and Y coordinates of the image.

A simple code what I tried:

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.aspect-ratio-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="img.jpg" class="aspect-ratio-img" alt="Your Image">
  <div class="overlay">Element</div>
  </img>
</div>
```

Result:
[image]

**But this is wrong**. In the example, the "element" text should have been kept over the same column and row of the grid. But as I show in the image it maintains the Top and Left relative to the browser edge and not based on the position of the image

**What would like to have is something like next gif:**
[image]

1. Background image **maintains proportions** and **resize horizontally and vertically** with the browser window
2. Foreground elements **keep the position in the same X,Y** coordinates of the background image.**And also resizes** (like using transform)

If I find the solution, I will post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a component with a slot which all you place there will be resized.
I'm not using JQuery, but I use the library [vue3-resize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-resize), you can also implement it without this library due to the VUE3 observer feature
This solution was based in the post https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/#article-header-id-1
Thanks a lot

```
    <script setup lang="ts">
    import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
    import 'vue3-resize/dist/vue3-resize.css'
    
    const bodyMapContainer = ref(null)
    const scalableContainer = ref(null)
    const scale = ref(0)
    
    onMounted(() => {
      doResize(bodyMapContainer.value.offsetWidth, bodyMapContainer.value.offsetHeight)
    })
    
    const handleResize = ({ width, height }) => {
      doResize(width, height)
    }
    
    const doResize = (width: number, height: number) => {
      const innerWidth = scalableContainer.value.offsetWidth
      const innerHeight = scalableContainer.value.offsetHeight
    
      scale.value = Math.min(width / innerWidth, height / innerHeight)
    }
    </script>
    
    <template>
      <div ref="bodyMapContainer" class="body-map-container">
        <resize-observer @notify="handleResize" />
        <div
          ref="scalableContainer"
          class="scalable-container"
          :style="{ transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%) ' + 'scale(' + scale + ')' }"
        >
          <slot></slot>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    <style>
    .body-map-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0 auto;
      left: 0%;
    }
    .scalable-container {
      width: 1000px;
      height: 750px;
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform-origin: center center;
    }
    </style>
```

Use:

```
        <ViewBoxPanel>
        ... place here everything you want
        <ViewBoxPanel>
``
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy with grid - you can style the grid any way you like but here I "super centered" it and used an area name to put both elements at the same grid quadrant then used negative margins to move the text a bit.

I changed the layout to put the div outside the image to further illustrate placement of that element vs "flow" where it would normally be below.

Keep in mind for this example the image will scale a bit but that is just style which can be set with size, aspect ratio etc.

NOTE: if you truly want a "grid" you can set the background of the container then set rows/columns on the grid of the size you wish then place the text in any grid cell you wish.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-container {
  background-color: #0000ff20;
  margin: 2em;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100vh;
  grid-template-areas: "herewego";
  place-items: start;
}

.grid-block {
  grid-area: herewego;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.my-image-block {
  border-color: #00FF00;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: red;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding-top: 1.125em;
  padding-left: 3.125em;
  border-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container grid-container">
  <div class="my-image-block grid-block">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="smallGrid" width="8" height="8" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><path d="M 8 0 L 0 0 0 8" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="0.5"/></pattern>
        <pattern id="grid" width="80" height="80" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <rect width="80" height="80" fill="url(#smallGrid)"/>
          <path d="M 80 0 L 0 0 0 80" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="1"/>
        </pattern>
      </defs>
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grid)" />
  </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay grid-block">Element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly, the code you provided doesn't work. I will edit your comment to post the gift with the execution (I can't post images in this response).
Thanks very much

Comment: Please update your question with a linkable image or perhaps an SVG we can use in questions with that "grid thing" if possible.  SO to clarify **you want both the image and text to scale**- BUT also keep the image AND TEXT aspect ratio of 1-1- for BOTH?

Comment: Note the image you put in does NOT whereas the example I did DOES scale the image with the same  aspect ratio so something differs there.

Comment: Hi Mark, I updated my question after reading your response. I understood that maybe my question wasn't enough clear.

The result that I am looking for is the last image (gif) of the question.
In WPF we can do it with a ViewBox for example. Also is possible with HTML canvas, but I didn't find a solution with CSS. 

I am using VUE3, but I think this was irrelevant in order I am only requesting help for HTML5+CSS

Comment: I used an image of a grid to note better that the text wasn't in the same row/column, but it was only an image. 

I wanted to create a human body with annotations and marks and all resizable (height and width) in a window (Electron.js) so all, body image and annotations have to be in the same proportion.

Comment: I did some adjustments  - note I put the "E" in Element at a specific grid location in my SVG grid using top and left margins - now when it scales (try zoom in/out etc.) the E stays at the same grid location as the grid - both are at the same grid location by using the same grid-area name.  The example has a bit of odd styling with borders and such just to try to show what is where.

Comment: Hi Mark and thank you very much for your help. Your last solution also doesn't resize the element to be in the same proportion.
I think it is something CSS can't do by itself. Take a look at my solution, It is specifically for VUE3 because I needed it, but it's based on this another https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/#article-header-id-1 (I removed the JQuery library and used a VUE3 feature instead)